# VBA Code in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, although it states there is an error.
What i want to do is complete csv file export from the current active sheet, and save it with the information currently in cell `A2`.

```
Sub exportCSV()
     ' export Macro

    Range("A:F").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    strName = AprilPayslips.Range("A2")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strName
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Posting the error, would help the clarity of your question

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value of a cell as a string then ask for it :)

```
strName = Range("A2").Value
```

These two lines won't do anything as they stand, so remove them:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Paths should always include the trailing slash so you don't need to add that in:

```
Sub exportCSV()
    strName = Range("A2").Value
    Range("A:F").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & strName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Should work for you, however unless you can be sure that the contents of A2 will always be a valid filename you may run into problems unless you add in some extra validation.